# Download Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I think I have looked at everywhere... but can anyone supply a link to download Visual Studio so that I can program in Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: Do you have to maintain a legacy app? I hope you do!

Comment: I do have to maintain legacy apps (I have been asked to do so).. not sure why the first responder voted my question down. I am on my own to do this

Comment: The only real way to get it now is to get a copy from someone that has it (and it's old), buy it from some used software vendor, or get it from your work. If you've been asked to do this, why don't they have a copy for you?

Comment: A free download? That's not going to be legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get an [MSDN subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb841434.aspx). It usually includes Visual Basic 6. Other distribution is almost certainly illegal.

Comment: VB6/VS6 and other legacy products were removed from MSDN  5 years ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2005/12/07/501169.aspx

Comment: Edit of my last: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2005/12/07/501169.aspx mentions it isn't available, but apparently you can still get some version depending on MSDN level. It'll still set you back the cost of MSDN, which is a nice tool but if you want to save money, you can get it cheaper elsewhere.

Comment: No, VB6 is still available from MSDN, it wasn't infected with any Sun property.  VB5 however is not available.

Comment: Edited post accordingly--I can confirm VB6 is still on my subscription, though I hope I never need it. :)

Comment: You can buy a second-hand copy on EBay or somewhere else. I Am Not A Lawyer, but provided you buy a genuine version, it might be legal: the seller is transferring their license to you. You as the buyer are taking it on good faith that the seller has uninstalled it. Contrastingly downloading it free from some third-party is in my opinion certainly illegal.